# GridSearchCV is very slow to estimate my model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, mlp

**I am using GridSearchCV on an MLP Classifier, this is my code...**

```
normalized_features.shape # (50000,784)
len(labels)               #  50000
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(normalized_features, labels, test_size=0.2)
mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter=100)
parameter_space = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [(50,50,50), (50,100,50), (100,)],
    'activation': ['tanh', 'relu'],
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam'],
    'alpha': [0.0001, 0.05],
    'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive'],
}
```

**This is the stage where I got struck, It's been more than two hours and still it keeps on loading and throws warnings**

```
clf = GridSearchCV(mlp, parameter_space, n_jobs=-1, cv=10)
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

*Warnings:*

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py:706: UserWarning: A worker stopped while some jobs were given to the executor. This can be caused by a too short worker timeout or by a memory leak.
>     "timeout or by a memory leak.", UserWarning

Can anyone please help me out with this and let me know where did I go wrong!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/ray-project/tune-sklearn - this package speeds up large hyperparameter tuning processes

Answer (score 2):

You are training (train and validation) on `50000` samples of `784` features over the parameter space of `3 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 3 = 72` with CV of `10`, which mean you are training `10` model each `72` times. Run it once with one set of parameters and and you can roughly extrapotate how much time it will take for your setup. It will take time for sure.

Answer (score 2):

As @mujjiga mentioned Gridsearch will try `72` different parameter combination for your each fold and if you have `10` fold the total model number that will be trained is `720`.

You may be want to use RandomizedSearch which will give you similar result with GridSearch method with less experiment. So you can decrease the time of your training.

You can find **`randomizedsearch`** implementation in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html).

Also you can read the comparision between gridsearch and randomizedsearch via this [link](https://blog.usejournal.com/a-comparison-of-grid-search-and-randomized-search-using-scikit-learn-29823179bc85) with more detail.